# angular 5 multiple router-outlets and submodules

Tags: angular, module, angular5, router-outlet

After going through the documentation and all the other questions, I am still unable to get a viable option working for my project. I've gone away from the named router-outlets option because it makes the url not as clean. It looks like with a lot of the answers (and I use the term lightly since most are either incomplete, unverified, or people still had questions in the comments) seem to be for older versions of angular, which might be why they aren't working as a solution for me. Any other options that might be presented would be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to use two separate router-outlets - one to distinguish between logged in and not, and one for some dynamically updated components once a user is verified. Before I had a login requirement, the router-outlet was inside my main component next to another component that had the router links. Right now with the login feature, the best I can get it to do is have all the components go through the first router-outlet - but this wrecks the sister components that should be displayed.

My app currently is structured like so:

```
    app/
      |  app.module.ts
      |  app-routing.module.ts
      |  app.component.html
      |  components/
      |  |  header-comp/
      |  |  login-comp/
      |  |  sub-module/
      |  |  |  detail-comp/
      |  |  |  list-comp/
      |  |  |  new-comp/
      |  |  |  main-comp/
      |  |  sub.module.ts
      |  |  sub-routing.module.ts
```

The app.module.ts:

```
    import {...} from ...;
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        LoginComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        SubModule,
        SubRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ...
      ],
      providers: [...],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

The app-routing.module:

```
    import {...} from ...;
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'app/components/sub-module/sub.module#SubModule' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];
    export const AppRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

the app.component.html - this should toggle between the login page or '' which would then load the submodule and display the main.component.html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <app-header></app-header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

the sub.module.ts:

```
    import {...} from ...;
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        DetailComponent,
        ListComponent,
        NewComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        SubRoutingModule,
        ...
      ],
      bootstrap: [MainComponent]
    })
    export class SubModule { }
```

The sub-routing.module:

```
    import {...} from ...;
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
    const subRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', children: [
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MainComponent },
          { path: 'new', pathMatch: 'full', component: NewComponent },
          { path: 'items/:id', pathMatch: 'full', component: DetailComponent },
      ] }
    ];
    export const SubRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(subRoutes);
```

the main.component.html - this should always be loaded if a user is logged in. it displays three other components (two of which, the new and detail components, are through my desired second router-outlet) and is passing @Input information to the list component:

```
    <div>
      <div class="col-2 list list-group">
        <app-list [AllItems]="items" [routeId]="routeId"></app-list>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10 main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The list.component.html has the routerlink for the detail component:

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of AllItems">
        <a [routerLink]="['/items', item.id]">
          <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I'd like to be able to use that second router outlet as the primary outlet once logged in because hard coding in the app-new and app-detail components instead would be really cumbersome and defeat the purpose of my using the routes and input features - the dynamic utility of the page would be lost. I really only need the first outlet to determine if someone is logged in or not, it seems a waste of the router outlet if I can't turn it off/get around it somehow.

A second pair of eyes would be much appreciated! (I'm open to restructuring back to a single router file and no submodule as well if someone thinks that will work better.)

Comment: If you would like a second pair if eyes, post your code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I think a single router structure would totally suit your needs.

Before you want to achieve something by using **router-outlets**, think carefully is this really the best option?

What I understand is that you want to achieve the following 2 requirements:

- to distinguish between logged in and not
- to dynamically updated some components

If that's the case, the first requirement can be achieved by simply use 2 different components for login/logout users.

```
<app-component-when-login *ngIf="isLogin"></app-component-when-login>
<app-component-when-logout *ngIf="!isLogin"></app-component-when-logout>
```

For the 2nd requirement, a children router-outlets should do the trick.

I would recommend an easy way to check if you really need router-outlets to get involved or not. Which is that **if this feature needs to make the current state reflected in the URL**, then yes you can use router-outlets, otherwise, you don't have to. Cuz it just making simple things over complicated.